# What is the difference between strategy.order() and strategy.entry()

Tags: pine-script

I have a problem,
I don't know the difference between strategy.order() and strategy.entry().
Can you tell me ? Thanks.

BTW, Pine script(strategy) Can entry long order and short order at the same time?
Example, maybe I have a long order, but I don't want to exit this order, and I want to entry a short order, can I do it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`strategy.order()` function does not take the pyramiding into account. That means when we submit entry orders with this function, they’re executed regardless of the number of currently open entries. While the `strategy.entry()` function does respect the strategy’s pyramiding settings, we can still end up with a bigger position than we allowed with the pyramiding settings.

Read more about differences here:

https://kodify.net/tradingview/orders/strategy-entry/

https://kodify.net/tradingview/strategy-settings/pyramiding-strategy-order/

Comment: The fact that strategy.entry() respects pyramiding also means that it can reverse market position correctly.